how to Insert XML with more than 4000 bytes characters into a Oracle XMLTYPE column for oracle database 11.2.0.4.0 gr2
i am trying to insert XML with more than 4000 bytes characters into a Oracle XMLTYPE column and i have this error :
ora-06502: pl/sql: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
i try  to "set max_string_size='EXTENDED' " in my oracle version 11gr2
but their is no parameter name max_string_size

That parameter was added in a later version so you're stuck with 4000 bytes. You haven't said how you are trying to insert, or where the XML value is coming from. If you're just cutting and pasting it into an insert then you'll have to chop it up into smaller chucks and build those into a CLOB. But maybe you are passing it into a procedure as the wrong data type; or could read it from a file. Please edit your question to explain/show what you are actually doing.

Apart from what Alex said, to remove other ambiguities, also specify the Oracle version you're using. Please show us how you're adding the XML. Just to clarify: you're inserting an XML, not registering an XSD, correct?

See https://docs.oracle.com/en/error-help/db/ora-06502/

What did you try?

If you are using string literals in a query then each literal cannot be more than 4000 bytes long. You need to split the string literal into chunks and concatenate them together ensuring that the first literal is either wrapped in TO_CLOB or appended to a CLOB:
CREATE TABLE table_name (xml XMLTYPE);

INSERT INTO table_name (xml)
VALUES (
  XMLTYPE(
   TO_CLOB('<root>First 4000 bytes ...')
    || 'Second 4000 bytes ...'
    || 'Third 4000 bytes ...'
    || 'Etc. ...</root>'
  )
);

or:
INSERT INTO table_name (xml)
VALUES (
  XMLTYPE(
    EMPTY_CLOB()
    || '<root>First 4000 bytes ...'
    || 'Second 4000 bytes ...'
    || 'Third 4000 bytes ...'
    || 'Etc. ...</root>'
  )
);

fiddle
